An error occurs when playing back video in h.265 format
An error occurs when playing back video in h.265 format - console.js:273 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported playlists.
code example:
useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      playerRef.current = videojs(videoRef.current, {
        controls: true,
        responsive: true,
        fluid: true,
        techOrder: ['html5'],
        html5: {
          hls: {
            overrideNative: true,
          },
        },
        sources: [
          {
            src: 'https://stream.cctv.teorema.info/9f49ae2b-7bc7-46dc-b400-58a98455458c/index.m3u8',
            // src: 'https://stream.cctv.teorema.info/36110638-7406-4a0a-83a8-831d4ece438f/index.m3u8',
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
          },
        ],
      });

      playerRef.current.on('error', () => {
        const error = playerRef.current?.error();
        if (error) {
          console.error('VideoJS Error:', error.message);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        if (playerRef.current) {
          playerRef.current.dispose();
        }
      };
    }
  }, [stream]);

